# PayPal Order Summary - increase displayed text length?

Tags: paypal, opencart

I run an e-commerce store (on OpenCart) and use both PayPal Standard and PayPal Express Checkout as payment methods.

When customers go on PayPal Order Summary to pay for the products, however, they are unable to see the full product details, as those are being cut:

Example image: http://s21.postimg.org/y25eelk1j/Capture.jpg

As you can see, the item description gets cut over a defined characters limit, whereas, customers have requested to see the complete text.

How could that be achieved (in OpenCart or in theory, at least)? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Open `catalog/controller/payment/pp_standard.php` and find this code

```
'value' => (utf8_strlen($value) > 20 ? utf8_substr($value, 0, 20) . '..' : $value)
```

change the two `20` values to a higher value of your choosing and save

Comment: What you suggest makes complete sense! Unfortunately, I've tried it and it doesn't make any difference. Perhaps there may be additional files involved or something?

Comment: There aren't any additional files no. The modification above will send more of the option name to paypal - however paypal itself limits the text. You will notice if you hover your mouse over the truncated option it will show more text than is displayed in blue - example: http://oi42.tinypic.com/2czeul4.jpg

Comment: Thank you for a prompt response!
Yes, I myself am completely happy with the hoverbox text. Unfortunately, it is customers that have demanded the full text in the non-hover state. Am I right to understand that it is a limitation of the PayPal Order Summary page and there is no way to modify static text length?

Comment: Yes that's correct. You have a couple of options really. The first is to move to something like PayPal pro and have the full summary on the checkout pages of your own store. The second is to use a different gateway completely. I may be wrong but I'm pretty sure that PayPal standard will actually show the full text in anything within PayPal itself such as the item summary within paypal's transactions - it just doesn't on that page as it has limited space